# Localhost MAMP does not get file contents from external webpage

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I have installed MAMP version 5.5 and am using PHP 7.3.8.

I have switched on the `allow_url_fopen = On` in the php.ini file in the MAMP application

(MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/conf/php.ini)

I have tested to fetch the localhost like:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost");
```

which works fine.

How ever as soon as I am trying to get external page the page is loading at snails pace and the it tells me it's timed out.

for example:

```
file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=".$origin."&destinations=".$destination."&key=".$api"")
```

I have the feeling it is something in the MAMP settings as this seems to work on a live server.
Any help welcome

Comment: The live server has to allow the access too.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  thanks for you reply, however what would be the live server setting to allow that as I would like it to work on the local

Comment: You wouldn't have control over the live server settings. It is likely that a host running on your computer is not allowed access to the Google API's where an actual online website would have access.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is not only google API it is any external website I just used the google as an example

Comment: Again, any external website may deny access when the request is coming from a local machine even if all you're doing is using it form development. Or if not the websites, your ISP may be blocking these requests for "security reasons"